# SSIS error 0x80040E14- unable to select data from temp table in Data flow task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

In SSIS package, There is an Execute Sql Task with below sql statement:

```
select c1, c2,c3
into #TempTable
from Source_Table
```

Then in Data Flow Task, there is OLE DB Source that select data from temp as mentioned below:

```
select c1, c2,c3
from #TempTable
```

Issue I am facing is the Error

> OX80040E14 SQL server native 11: Description: Unable to prepare SQL
> statments, Invalid object #TempTable

in Execute SQL Task I did the setting for Resultset= Single Row

Also set `RetainSameConnection=True`

Comment: Temporary tables only exists for the scope they are created in, and can only be access by that scope (and any child scopes). If you `CREATE` a temporary table in an Execute SQL Task, is will be (long) gone by the time your data flow connects to the instance. It's very likely you *do not* want a temporary table here.

Comment: @ThomA, but i gave seen in some og the packages they have used temp table is ExecuteSQL task and that being called in DataFlow.

Comment: Also, i tried using Global Temp ..but still not working

Comment: I suspect you are mistaken. Or, perhaps, you have seen the use of "global" temporary table and they are using a sequence container.

Comment: @ThomA Yes, there is a squence container containing both Execute SQL task and Then DataFlow

Comment: So finally I got the issue resolved like this, created the tempdb..#tableName is SSMS first and copied the code to Execute SQL task and later created mapping in OLE DB source DB task. Now the column mapping can be clicked and edited as the table is present in tempDb.